# Generating pandas column values based upon filename

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to populate three columns (day, week, year) in a pandas data frame.

The data is to be extracted from a filename which are in this format:

```
AAAA_DDWWYYYY.txt
```

where:

- AAAA = alpha characters
- DD = Day
- WW = Month
- YYYY = Year

For example:

```
NDVI_01012016.txt
```

is:

- Day = 01
- Week = 01
- Year = 2016

Comment: this question is incredibly vague, you've not posted sample raw data, your code attempts, the desired output and any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your dataframe::

```
df.ix[df.filename == 'NDVI_01012016.txt', 'Day'] = 1
df.ix[df.filename == 'NDVI_01012016.txt', 'Week'] = '01'
df.ix[df.filename == 'NDVI_01012016.txt', 'Year'] = '2016'
```